# "Community was here" vs "Community existed"

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between the following two:

> I didn't know if this community existed
>
> I didn't know if this community was here

Comment: Would you be so kind as to edit your question to expand on what differences you find between "existed" and "was here"?

Comment: Compare "I didn't know the King of Spain existed" and "I didn't know the King of Spain was here". There's a difference.

Comment: @MattЭллен: Edited.

Comment: "I didn't know the King of Spain existed/was here" is a different comparison from "I didn't know if this community existed/was here." The *if* changes everything.

Comment: @Robusto: you're right, of course. I dropped the *if* without intending to; I think because I would use *whether* instead in these sentences. But compare *"I didn't know if the King of Spain existed"* and *"I didn't know if the King of Spain was here"*.  The *existed/was here* difference isn't affected by the *if*.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is incorrect - you have your tenses mixed up. It should read:

> I didn't know if this community existed.

Once that has been corrected, both mean broadly the same thing.

I would, however, have worded them slightly differently:

> I didn't know this community existed.
>
> I didn't know this community was here.

After your comments, however, the meaning can be very different:

> The king of Spain was here

means that the king was in this place, but

> The king of Spain existed

is confirming that there is a king of Spain.

Answer (score 0):

`I didn't know if this community existed` states that I was completely unaware of the fact that this community existed.

Whereas `I didn't know if this community was here` states that i was aware of the fact that this community existed, but i did not know that it was here.